# Check and copy values from bash array to json array

Tags: python, arrays, json, bash, jq

I have two bash arrays.

ID=(1 2 3 4...)
VALUES=("/path1" "/path2" "/path3" "/path4"...)

And I want to add the corresponding values to a JSON array

```
[
{
  "Id": "1",
  "Path": "/path1"
},
{
  "Id": "2",
  "Path": "/path2"
}
...
]
```

Before adding the values, I want to check if the element already exists and skip if it does. How can I go about implementing this in a bash script (or python, if that's better)

Answer (score 1):

The requirements are not entirely clear to me, but the following should be sufficient to get you on your way.

Please note that the following assumes that raw newlines appear in neither ID nor VALUES.

Notice also that in the following, the first and last elements of each of the ID and VALUES arrays are the same.  This is to exercise one of the requirements.

```
#!/bin/bash
ID=(1 2 3 4 1)
VALUES=("/path1" "/path2" "/path3" "/path4" "/path1")

ID=$(printf "%s\n" "${ID[@]}")
VALUES=$(printf "%s\n" "${VALUES[@]}")

jq -n --arg id "$ID" --arg values "$VALUES" '
  # emit a dictionary
  def set(s): reduce s as $x ({};
    .[$x | (type[0:1] + tostring)] = $x);

  # distinct entities in the stream s
  def distinct(s): set(s)[];

  [$id, $values]
  | map( split("\n"))
  | [distinct(transpose[])]
  | map( {Id: .[0], Path: .[1]} )
'
```

We use `set/1` and `distinct/1` rather than `unique` mainly to ensure that the ordering is retained as the requirements specify, but also to avoid the `sort` that `unique` entails.

### Output:

```
[
  {
    "Id": "1",
    "Path": "/path1"
  },
  {
    "Id": "2",
    "Path": "/path2"
  },
  {
    "Id": "3",
    "Path": "/path3"
  },
  {
    "Id": "4",
    "Path": "/path4"
  }
]
```